# Why am I getting this errors in Next js build command?

Tags: next.js, deployment, tailwind-css

Hi I'm using next js version 13 with tailwind css .
I have a problem with deploying my project.

```
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/static/css/e7648b03c0d65889.css:1468:189: Unknown word
    at makeWebpackError (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:311209)
    at /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:106058
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:34:1)
-- inner error --
CssSyntaxError: /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/static/css/e7648b03c0d65889.css:1468:189: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:594:22)
    at ScssParser.other (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:436:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:471:16)
    at scssParse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:48:12)
    at /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:80:55
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:105:20)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
CssSyntaxError: /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/static/css/e7648b03c0d65889.css:1468:189: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:594:22)
    at ScssParser.other (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:436:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:471:16)
    at scssParse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:48:12)
    at /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:80:55
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:105:20)
```

## This is my next configs

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

## This is my tailwind css configs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}' , './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      boxShadow: {
        'customeOne' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0px 1px 3px 0px, rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.15) 0px 0px 0px 1px;',
        'customeTwo' : 'rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 2px 5px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 3px -1px;',
        'customeThree' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 15px 25px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 5px 10px;',
        'customeFour' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 0px 1px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 0px 4px 8px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 0px 8px 16px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 0px 16px 32px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 0px 32px 64px;',
        'customeFive' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;'
      }
    },
  },
};
```

## Package json

```
{
  "name": "next-first-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "server": "json-server --watch server/db.json --port 5000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "json-server": "^0.17.4",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

## Post css config js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

## My global css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer base {
    input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
```

I've tried multipul ways to fix it such as rewriting dynamic sizes in tailwind like ( w-[20rem] ) . changing next configs , reinstalling tailwind with V2 documents etc but nothing really changed the situation .